# Unsaving/resetting user edits from an element in local storage

Tags: javascript

I cannot seem to figure out how I can remove the user edits from a single element from the local storage of the website planner I am trying to make.

The planner shows the next seven days, and the user can add notes to each day. The user has the option to save the notes separately for each day (by pressing a "Save Day" button), with each day a separate element that saves into local storage and that works all fine. I want to give the user a way to clear their notes for each separate day by pressing a "Reset Day" button, but I cannot figure out how to do that. I can clear everything at once with localStorage.clear();, but I want each element to be able to be cleared individually.

```
<script>
function resetEdits1() {    
localStorage.removeItem("edit1");
}
</script>
```

I have tried this but I don't think this works with elements (like "edit1").

```
<script>
function saveEdits1() { 
var editElem = document.getElementById("edit1");
var userVersion = editElem.innerHTML;
localStorage.userEdits1 = userVersion;
}
</script>
```

This is how I save an element into the local storage. I'm trying to reverse that process to go back to what the element was like before edits were made and added to local storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your given code, you never set the localStorage item 'edit1'. So, obviously it can't be removed, if it doesn't exist. The only localStorage item, which you might have set is 'userEdits1'. So, you would need to use

```
localStorage.removeItem("userEdits1");
```

to remove it.

I think, it would be helpful for you to have another look at how to set, get and remove items from the localStorage. [This site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) might be helpful for that.

Comment: Will do. Thank you :)